# Is there a way to add Chrome Dedicated Developer Tools to Chrome Apps list?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging server side code with Chrome Inspector, you have to reload Inspector every time you restart the server (as the URI changes). I eventually found out that if you use the `Open dedicated DevTools for Node` link in `chrome://inspect/#devices`, this tool will automatically reload with a node restart. This tool is also cool because you get a new window with the app as a full-page, like:

[image]

So, here's the questie: Is it possible to add `Open Dedicated DevTools` as an App to Chrome's Apps page?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to add it as an app? What're you aiming to accomplish?

Comment: Because I do not want to have to bookmark `chrome://inspect#devices`. If I can bookmark the DevTools directly, that would also work, but I am not seeing this as a normal link. Also, new tabs automatically open up to Apps, and it just makes sense for this to be an app, like Postman.